# Is there anyway to hold response until we get full response from server in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

The services I'm trying to test, will work on long pooling method.

They won't give results in first response.

When I run my API script I am not getting full response in first time.

How can I wait in this case for the remaining portion of response to be received?

I want to use values from this response into next call..

[image]
In the above screen my response should wait when complete:True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your requirement you need to repeat the `Gethotels` request until `complete` attribute becomes `true`.

In order to accomplish this:

1. Add a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the `Gethotels` request and set it up as follows:

   [image]
2. Put your `Gethotels` request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) and use the following [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${complete}" != "true",)}
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, While Controller loop the `Gethotels` request until `complete` becomes `true`

   [image]